# Accurate A* search heuristic for isometric maps?

Tags: algorithm, search, heuristics, a-star, isometric

I have written an implementation of the A* search algorithm. The problem is that the heuristic I'm currently using only works accurately on square grids. As my map is isometric, the heuristic doesn't take into account *actual* the layout of the map and thus, the distance between cells.

**Update:** After extensive logging and analysis (read as *spending lots of time trying to figure out a banality*), I have come to the conclusion that my current heuristic works quite well, with one little exception: the end result is reversed for *real* straight and diagonal movement.

```
inline int Pathfinder::calculateDistanceEstimate(const CellCoord& coord) const
{
    int diagonal = std::min(abs(coord.x-goal->position.x), abs(coord.y-goal->position.y));
    int straight = (abs(coord.x-goal->position.x) + abs(coord.y-goal->position.y));
    return 14 * diagonal + 10 * (straight - 2 * diagonal);
}
```

This means that a straight move, which really costs `sqrt(2)` times more than a diagonal move on an *isometric* map, is calculated to be the that of a diagonal one. The question is: how can I modify my current heuristic so it will produce correct results for an isometric layout? Simply replacing `diagonal` with `straight` and vice versa will *not* work.

[image: Map layout]

Comment: You've said you're looking to repair the heuristic; can you post the code relevant to the heuristic? Or alternatively enough of the code that we can determine a solution?

Comment: Is your heuristic... pixel-based? Manhattan distance is typical for a square grid map, and should be easy to translate to isometric, seeing as you probably store a map in a square matrix anyhow. Regardless, posting a hint as to how your current heuristic works, and how you represent the map internally, would be quite helpful. CoderTao, I think, has the right idea in his answer, but I too am confused as to why his suggestion would require a complete re-write.

Comment: My heuristic is not pixel based, and my map is not stored in a square matrix, hence the rewrite. The map would be stored in a square matrix if it was, e.g. diamond shaped. The map is projected as a rectangle.

Comment: Yes; but each square in the map is still a set of two coordinates. We aren't suggesting a massive rewrite of everything; just a bit of data processing when calculating the heuristic. Ultimately we still need a better description to be able to better advise you on what course to take. (Example: I've been talking about how to fix the distance till completion portion of algorithm; on rereading, it sounds like you're having trouble with just the 'distance to get here' portion)

Comment: The 'distance to get here' portion *is* the heuristic. And what I need, is a heuristic which accounts for the irregularity of the map's layout.

Comment: Is the revised answer any better? Or alternatively; what are the short comings with it? (We do like to help... just getting on the same page can be difficult)

Comment: Okay, so, one more time, what are you expecting as output from the heuristic? that distance(3,2; 3,3) < distance(3,1; 3,3) < distance(3,2; 3,3) ?

Comment: pretend that last one was distance(3,2; 3,3) < distance(3,1; 3,3) < distance(2,3; 3,3)

Comment: That's almost right. First cost is 10, second and third 14. But reread the updated question, if you will.

Comment: Okay; then I think the new solution might have it; the distance formula as posted gives values of 10, 20, and 10 for the above cases; the formula in my answer has 10, 14, 14. Barring a piece of the update that I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to try would be converting from isometric coordinates to a square grid coordinate set for all calculations.

Say that 0,0 stays the root of the map. 0,1 stays the same, 1,2 becomes 0,2; 1,3 becomes 0,3; 2,3 becomes 1,4; 3,3 becomes 2,5; 0,2 becomes -1,1; etc. This puts you back into a square grid such that the coordinates and heuristics should work again.

Y coordinate becomes Y+sourceX offset (3,3 is at x=2; so becomes 2,5); finding sourceX mathmatically is proving itself more difficult.

[Stream of consciousness; ignore] Isometric coordinates at Y=0 are accurate for source X. So, to calculate source X you need to 'move left/up Y times' which should net a change of Y/2; rounded down, in the X coordinate.... roughly suggesting that the square coordinates would be:

```
sourceX = X - Y/2
sourceY = Y + sourceX
```

Where sourceX and sourceY are the coordinates in a normal square grid; and Y/2 is integer arithmetic/rounded down.

So, in theory, this becomes:

```
double DistanceToEnd(Point at, Point end)
{
    Point squareStart = squarify(at);
    Point squareEnd = squarify(end);
    int dx=squareStart.X-squareEnd.X;
    int dy=squareStart.Y-squareEnd.Y;
    return Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}
Point squarify(Point p1)
{
     return new Point(p1.X-p1.Y/2, p1.Y+(p1.X-p1.Y/2));
}
```

**Update** based on new bits of question:

Assuming that you are trying to get distance(3,2; 3,3) < (distance(2,3; 3,3) = distance(3,1; 3,3)); the following should work: (translated from C#; typos not guaranteed to be non present)

```
inline int Pathfinder::calculateDistanceEstimate(const CellCoord& coord) const
{
    int cx=coord.x - coord.y/2;
    int cy=coord.y + cx;
    int gx=goal->position.x - goal->position.y/2;
    int gy=goal->position.y + gx;
    int diagonal = std::min(abs(cx-gx), abs(cy-gy));
    int straight = (abs(cx-gx) + abs(cy-gy));
    return 14 * diagonal + 10 * (straight - 2 * diagonal);
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed horrible typo.... again.

Comment: I need to fix the heuristic, not the algorithm itself, and doing this would require a complete change of the system.

Comment: Ultimately this should only change the Heuristic; if you try the heuristic for distance remaining as distance(squareCoords(current), squareCoords(dest)); you shouldn't need to make any other changes in the system.

Comment: Two things:

A) there's a typo
B) it's not giving me any better paths than my current heuristic, for a good reason: it's not taking into account diagonal movement

Comment: I take no responsibility for awful spelling. That said; what do you mean 'its not taking into account diagonal movement'? An explicit example of what it is doing on your end would be useful.

Comment: It's not making any diagonal moves whatsoever, unless you are moving to a tile which is adjacent.

Comment: That... doesn't make alot of sense. There shouldn't be a case where the algorithm would outright stall.... at some point it should exhaust all possibilities and give up; but it shouldn't be stalling.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant. But it takes some time to do that.

Comment: Okay; yet another horrible typo was probably present. I suspect I should have posted the C# code; gy=position.y + cy should have been gy=position.y+gx

Comment: Thanks for the code! I tweaked `return 14 * diagonal...` to `return 11 * diagonal...` and had better results, for what it's worth.

Answer (score -1):

[Amit](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/path.cpp) here computes the "manhattan distances for hexagons". Its C++ code, and I can't vouch for it, but Amit is a name I've heard before for game development.

The manhattan distance for hexagons should be suitable for a proper heuristic.

Edit: reversed the syntax for hyperlinking, whoops.

Comment: Unfortunately, tiles on a hexagonal grid only move in 6 directions, and the cost of moving is equal for every direction, so I can't use this.

Comment: My god, I completely misread your question. Somehow isometric became hexagonal. Sorry about that.